# Proving set of upper triangular matrices form subspace of $M_{m \times n}$ (F)

Tags: vector-spaces

Proving set of upper triangular matrices form subspace of $M_{m \times n}$ (F)

Now clearly if i set all elements including diagonal =0 then we can say that o vector is there. Also it satisfies additive closure and scalar closure. What else should i do in these types of questions

Thanks

Comment: Basicaly, just prove what you wrote in your question

Comment: @windircurse is that by taking elements of form a.b.c ,,, and doing this?

Comment: yeah, that's it

Comment: @windircurse OK THANKS

Comment: So, you need an exact definition for "upper triangular".  Then check the properties you mentioned using that definition.